# How do I use pagination in WordPress?

Tags: query-posts, pagination

I'm using the index.php file and editing this so that it displays two articles at a time. I'm using `query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=2' );` before the main loop and it's displaying what I want correctly.

How can I have a page navigation at the bottom?

Comment: do you have any reason not to use ***dashboard -> settings -> reading -> Blog pages show at most [] posts***

Comment: helpful link: http://skyje.com/2010/02/5-excellent-wordpress-pagination-solutions/

Comment: are you asking for wordpress functions such as `next_posts_link()`, `previous_posts_link()`, or `posts_nav_link()` or pagination plugins?

Answer (score 2):

As in the comments, it's not clear why you can't use the options: **dashboard -> settings -> reading -> Blog pages show at most [] posts**

However, if it is necessary that this be done via altering the query (say to target only specific pages, or archives) then this should really be done on `pre_get_post`:

For instance to change the post's per page for any archive for a term in the 'my-tax' taxonomy:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts','wpse26898_change_per_post');
function wpse26898_change_per_post( $query ){
    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_tax('my-tax') ){
        $query->set('posts_per_page'=>2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`query_posts` alters the main loop and messes up pagination.

Use `new WP_Query` to show your first 2 posts before the main loop.

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
    );

$myquery = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); 

//Do stuff

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

//Run main loop
```

Answer (score 0):

For custom queries you need to enable paging by including `$paged` in your query parameters.

`$paged` is a global that gets set/updated whenever you're within a query context. WordPress looks at the URL structure `/page/x` in the url to determine the page number, `x` being the number. It is then used by the standard paging functions eg. `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` until it is overwritten or reset using `wp_reset_query()`.

```
// new query that respects $paged
query_posts( $query_string . '&posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged );

if ( have_posts() ) :

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        get_template_part( 'post' );

    endwhile;

    // pagination links to show next 2 or previous 2 posts
    next_posts_link();
    previous_posts_link();

endif;

// return to the original URL query
wp_reset_query();
```